# Problem installing apache2

Tags: apt, package-management, apache2

If I enter:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

I get:

```
Setting up apache2-bin (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8) ...
Setting up apache2-data (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8) ...
Setting up apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8) ...
ERROR: Config file dir.conf not properly enabled: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf is a real file, not touching it
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
apache2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

input: `sudo apt-get install -f`

output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8) ...
ERROR: Config file dir.conf not properly enabled: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf is a real file, not touching it
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `sudo a2dismod dir; sudo apt-get install -f` Add the output to your question.

Comment: input: sudo a2dismod dir;

output: Disabling stale config file dir.conf.
ERROR: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf is not a symbolic link, not deleting

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 157 জানু    3  2014 /etc/apache2/mods-available/dir.conf

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  58 জানু    3  2014 /etc/apache2/mods-available/dir.load

Comment: output: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 117 নভে   27 10:16 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 117 নভে   27 10:16 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf~

-rw------- 1 root root   1 নভে   27 10:10 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf.save

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 117 নভে   27 10:28 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf.save.1

Comment: rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.*’: No such file or directory

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for apache2:amd64

Comment: Thanks brother for you help. my problem is solved. Thank a lot.

Comment: Actually your comment doesn't solve the problem. It doesn't remove the file. The answer solved the problem. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't have any apache2 configuration that you need, Try to resolve this by removing all apache2 files and configuration and install a new default configuration.

Try the following command to uninstall and remove configuration files.

(You need to stop the apache service **before** you uninstall):

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2*
```

And install it again by typing:

```
apt-get install apache2
```

Comment: And all configurations? Sure not.

Comment: Thanks brother it works, i was trying this for more than 5 hours. I am really thankful to you.  Could you help to rate this. or marked it solved. i am using ubuntu just for 2 days.